# How to deserialize asynchronously using System.Text.Json library?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, system.text.json

I have a json that I am deserializing by using NewtonSoftJson Json library as shown below:

```
public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext, ISchema schema)
{
    ...
    var request = Deserialize<GraphQLRequest>(httpContext.Request.Body);
    ....
}

public static T Deserialize<T>(Stream s)
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(s))
    using (var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(reader))
    {
        var ser = new JsonSerializer();
        return ser.Deserialize<T>(jsonReader);
    }
}
```

Now I am trying to use `System.Text.Json` library to deserialize asynchronously so I read their docs and they do have `DeserializeAsync` method which I can use but when I replace content of above method like below then I get compilation error -

```
public static T Deserialize<T>(Stream s)
{
  return JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<GraphQLRequest>(s, new JsonSerializerOptions
      {
          PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true
      }
  );
}
```

Error I get is -

```
Cannot convert expression type 'System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask<App.Api.Kestrel.GraphQLRequest?>' to return type 'T'
```

I am new to dotnet world so kinda confuse what is wrong I am doing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `public static T Deserialize<T>(Stream s)` is a [generic method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-methods) where `T` is type parameter which is passed by user, so you need to deserialize to `T`, not to `GraphQLRequest`.
2. async methods usually ([but not always](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/async-return-types)) retrun `Task`'s, so you need to change your signature and implementation accordingly resulting in:

```cs
public static async Task<T> Deserialize<T>(Stream s)
{
  return await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<T>(s, new JsonSerializerOptions
      {
          PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true
      }
  );
}
```

And then pass concrete type in the invocation (and use `await`):

```
public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext, ISchema schema)
{
    ...
    GraphQLRequest request = await Deserialize<GraphQLRequest>(httpContext.Request.Body);
    ....
}
```

Since [`JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializer.deserializeasync?view=net-5.0#System_Text_Json_JsonSerializer_DeserializeAsync__1_System_IO_Stream_System_Text_Json_JsonSerializerOptions_System_Threading_CancellationToken_) returns a [`ValueTask`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/understanding-the-whys-whats-and-whens-of-valuetask/) another option is to pass it through without awaiting:

```cs
public static ValueTask<T> Deserialize<T>(Stream s)
{
  return JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<T>(s, new JsonSerializerOptions
      {
          PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true
      }
  );
}
```

The calling code will not change.

Comment: Now it makes sense as I understood what I was missing. Also if my json fails to deserialize then `System.Text.Json` library will throw `System.Text.Json.JsonException` always or is there any case where it can throw some other exceptions for deserialization? I was looking at the docs and source code but couldn't see it clearly what it will throw so I wanted to make sure on that. But when I read `JsonException` class there it is clearly mentioned so just wanted to make sure

Comment: @AndyP documentation for [`DeserializeAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializer.deserializeasync?view=net-5.0)  linked in answer lists exceptions thrown by the method,

Comment: Note from [PropertyNameCaseInsensitive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializeroptions.propertynamecaseinsensitive): "There is a performance cost associated with case-insensitive comparison (that is, when PropertyNameCaseInsensitive is true)."